# Laws of "Shehiyah" relating to a "Chayah"

Tags: animals, slaughter-shochet-shecht

In the Shulchan Arukh ([Yoreh Deah Siman 23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=64)) we find the laws of "shehiyah", which relates to the laws of shechita. This is basically a prohibition stating that one may not pause in the middle of the shechita. These halachos are complicated with many nuances, including differences between a "behama" (domesticated land animal) and an "oif" (bird). What about a "chayah" (non-domesticated animal)? This is a separate category of animal with differences in Halacha from behama and oif in other areas of Halacha. Does it have it's own laws here as well, or is it categorized together with Behamas in regards to the dinim of Shehiyah. I haven't found this explicitly mentioned in the Siman yet.

Comment: Do you have reason to think it might take a different amount of time to slaughter another chaya vs another behema?

Comment: ומדלא אדכיר רבי יוסי בר חנינא עוף **משמע דליכא אלא הני תרי שיעורי** דקה וגסה ובכלל דקה הוי שיעור עוף וכן דעת הרמב"ם בפ"ג מהלכות שחיטה (*Beis Yosef* ad loc. on the opinion of the Ran and the Rambam).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Behemah here means land animal, not necessarily domesticated.

Comment: @Fred there is a Behemah Daka and Behemah Gassa...That doesn't mean Chayah and Behemah

Comment: @Yehoshua That's exactly my point - there are only two categories (according to the BY's understanding of the Ran and Rambam); it doesn't matter if it's a chaya or a beheima. Even according to other rishonim, there is no reason to think that there would be a special standard for a chaya.

Comment: Would "pause" be a better translation for "shehiyah" than "interrupt"? I've also heard "wait", but that doesn't really carry the same meaning, at least as far as I understand it. What about "hesitate"? I'm not talking about the actual translation of the word; I'm referring to the meaning in terms of the act (or lack thereof) that is prohibited.

Comment: @SethJ I like 'pause'.

Comment: @DoubleAA the question doesn't exist though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Darkei Teshuvah Siman 23 Se'if Katan 22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4694&st=&pgnum=172) he brings [Shu"t Pri Ho'oretz (YD 1:4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1268&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) that a Chaya has the same Shiur of a Behema which is כדי שיגביה בהמה דקה וירביצנה וישחטנה. Then he brings the [Da'as Torah (YD 23 sk 4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8099&st=&pgnum=177) who learns that the Pri Megadim (YD MZ 28:16) holds that it's the same Shiur as a bird, and declares צ"ע (this requires further investigation) regarding the Pri Megadim! The Darkei Teshuvah explains that that is not what the Pri Megadim is really saying (and brings support to his view from Sefer Meged Shomayim).

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise noted, חיה בכלל בהמה ([Bava Kama 17b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=17b&format=pdf)).

Comment: I think your conclusion is right, but I don't know if that linguistic point about Mishnaic Hebrew usage applies to all further rabbinic writings and could then be used to prove it. IAE you still haven't shown, sourced or even claimed that a difference is not otherwise noted.

Comment: @DoubleAA 1. In my experience it has been used that way. I think I remember specifically an example by the Mechaber himself in the laws of excrement in the laws of Shema (I didn't check for it). 2. The author of the question himself says so. If you want, I can read through the chapter, but I think I can trust Yehoshua on that.

Comment: @ba as an example a chayan and oif need cisui dam, a behamah doesn't. so....Over here in my case it's a metzias on why the shiur of shehiyah would be more or less by a behemah or oif (or perhaps even chayah.) See the first Sif in SA and beginning of Simleh Chadasha

Comment: @Yehoshua - Re. kisui dam: it's because there is a pasuk that says so (Vayikra 17:13).

Comment: @Fred My point being that it's not the same always. Bad example but only thing that came to mind. We see chilukim between behamah and chayah though in other instances. This would seem to be the same if not more so. Or at least to know if a chayah is not like an oif in regards to this din.

Comment: @Yehoshua Does Rambam Shechita 1:1 clear this up for you?

Comment: @DoubleAA No, and why should it? I recently found mareh makomos to this that were quite obvious I will post them soon unless someone beats me to it. I don't think the Rambam was brought in the Achronim that speak about this.

Comment: @Yehoshua Because it says shechita for behema and chaya is the same, and in fact you have shown no differences _at all_ between them. (Note also the rambam says that the spilled blood of a chaya is the same as the spilled blood of a bird.)