# Cutting ones finger in the middle of shechting

Tags: animals, slaughter-shochet-shecht

If someone was shechting a chicken (for example) and by mistake cut their finger would their be reason to be concerned for the problem of "shehiyeh" ("pausing"). What about if the person accidentally cut the finger of the one who was holding the chicken. Do the poskim speak about these cases at all? If so who and what's the din?

(For more about what "shehiyah" is, [see here.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26275/laws-of-shehiyah-relating-to-a-chayah))

Comment: Why would cutting someone else's finger yield shehiyah? I'd be more interested in if it is a problem of chaladah, though I'd guess it isn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps at the moment he cuts his finger he would stop the process? I've heard the shailo before and am trying to find those that speak about it.

Comment: @Yehoshua, the hypothetical situation about if he would stop is obviously a problem. Are you asking if we _assume_ he stopped? Because if he _actually_ stopped, I believe you already know the answer.

Comment: Or are you asking if the cut is _considered_ a pause? Or something else?

Comment: @DoubleAA see שמלה חדשה at [23:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=98); the chashash is shehiyah.

Comment: Yehoshua: I edited my answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

I can't source this, but I would imagine that it would depend on whether or not the person holding the animal jumped -- see שמלה חדשה at [23:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=98), where he says that even where the שוחט cut his own finger, we are only worried where he noticed the cut before he finished שחיטה, and then only when he jumped.
As to the person holding the animal, he needs to hold it steady -- if it was not held steady, then there is a chashash of shehiyah, chalada. If his finger was cut, I would think he is not better or worse than the shochet himself.

**Edit:** When I wrote this answer, I had forgotten about what the Matteh Asher had written, [ad loc 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=98) --

> **אם שחט בעצבאו של האוחט הבעל חי, כשר בכל ענין**, שאין השוחט נבעת
>
> **if the knife cuts the finger of the guy holding the animal, then the שחיטה is absolutely kosher** (because there is no reason for the שוחט to jump at that)

[ *It should be noted that if the finger* nail *of the אוחז (or, indeed, that of the שוחט himself, יש להחמיר (but if they are absolutely certain that when the fingernail was cut, all cutting for the שחיטה stopped [and רוב was already achieved], one could be מיקל בהפסד מרובה)* ]